# Breakpoints not working in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

When I hit F5, my VS 2008 opens my site in IE and halts. There is no sign in VS that the project is running. It enables the RUN button again even though the site is opened in IE. Hence, my breakpoints are also not working.

This behaviour started happening suddenly..

Any reasons why it happens and resolutions?

Answer (score 1):

Are you building in Debug mode? Release builds don't support breakpoints...

Answer (score 0):

One reason I have personally experienced:

- **Problem:**
  Running two separate Solutions in their own instance of Visual Studio 2008
- **Solution:**
  I closed both instances of VS, then started only one.
- **Conclusion 1:** 
  Visual Studio might have a problem when RAM is limited and silently disable breakpoints (fail)
- **Conclusion 2:** 
  Visual Studio might share some critical resources needed for breakpointing which the first instance holds onto and (again silently) the other instance won't even give you an error.

Lots of bugs and fail in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late, but in case anyone else has this problem, I'll post these two links that helped me when I had a similar problem:

1. Forum describing similar problems: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/f3fcb4fb-8a08-4fa0-8d58-9ed6f3eb1193
2. Solution listed in the forum was this patch: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB957912/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1796